# On error -> cancel what already done

Tags: excel, error-handling, vba

Is there a way to say to the code that, everytime there is an error, cancel what it's previously done?
For example, I have a code which creates 6 workbooks and when there is an error at the half of the code I have to cancel every workbook and launch the macro again!

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
Application.UnDo
```

in your error code.  *It does not always work.*

Answer (score 0):

VBA execution causes the Undo history to be erased

- code that changes the interface in any way will clear the Undo buffer (stack)
- the history is a list (or collection) of strings

  - `Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").Control.ListCount` is 0

but you might be able to do something like this

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub makeFiles()
    Dim i As Long, currentWB As Long, newWBs As Long

    On Error GoTo cancelAction

    currentWB = Workbooks.Count
    For i = 1 To 6
        Workbooks.Add
        newWBs = newWBs + 1
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = 4

        'generate an error
        If i = 3 Then Workbooks.Item(Workbooks.Count + 1).Activate
    Next

cancelAction:

    Do While newWBs > 0     'Workbooks.Count > 1
        Workbooks(currentWB + newWBs).Close False
        newWBs = newWBs - 1
    Loop

End Sub
```